# Corpus suggestion for financial domain

Tags: nlp, finance, corpora, text

I am looking for a financial corpus or any form of publicly available financial texts which is replete with technical terms and acronyms.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127265/how-to-make-or-get-corpus-of-financial-documents

Answer (score 1):

The US Securities and Exchange Commission requires larger publicly traded companies to file quarterly and annual financial statements in [XMRL](https://www.xbrl.org/the-standard/why/xbrl-for-securities-filing/). These can be accessed from the agency's [EDGAR site](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/webusers.htm). In addition, fulsome textual discussion is required, and defined acronyms are common.

Comment: you mean xbrl; they claim to be open, but the only tools they build on are excel/sheets. sure, they have (horrible) html demos, but those reek of bait and switch. conversations with their team, as well as their data community show almost zero interest for non google, non microsoft entities. they also charge for membership, and membership grants you access to more of their "communities". team xbrl is open washing at its finest.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my dyslexia. I meant XBRL (https://www.sec.gov/structureddata/osd-inline-xbrl.html).